# concatenate an array to existing postgresql array

Tags: arrays, postgresql

I have a postgresql database for which each row has an existing array of integers. I want to concatenate the existing array for each row with a new array. I have tried the following per the docs (http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/static/functions-array.html), but these are all not working:

```
db=> update useradds set deals=array_append(deals, {4, 5});
ERROR:  syntax error at or near "{"
LINE 1: update useradds set deals=array_append(deals, {4, 5});
                                                      ^
db=> update useradds set deals=array_cat(deals,  {6,7});
ERROR:  syntax error at or near "{"
LINE 1: update useradds set deals=array_cat(deals,  {6,7});
                                                    ^
db=> update useradds set deals=array_cat(deals, {6,7});
ERROR:  syntax error at or near "{"
LINE 1: update useradds set deals=array_cat(deals, {6,7});
                                                   ^

db=> update useradds set deals=array_cat(deals,{6,7} );
ERROR:  syntax error at or near "{"
LINE 1: update useradds set deals=array_cat(deals,{6,7} );
                                                  ^
db=> update useradds set deals=array_cat(deals,{6} );
ERROR:  syntax error at or near "{"
LINE 1: update useradds set deals=array_cat(deals,{6} );
                                                  ^
db=> update useradds set deals=deals||{6,7};
ERROR:  syntax error at or near "{"
LINE 1: update useradds set deals=deals||{6,7};
                                         ^
db=> update useradds set deals = deals || {6,7};
ERROR:  syntax error at or near "{"
```

I am running v. 9.3.5. What's wrong with these calls? Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot to enter a array as `{6,7}`. There is two possibilities:

```
SELECT ARRAY[6,7];
SELECT '{6,7}'::int[]; -- **literal** casted as int array
```

When you can join two arrays, you have to use a `array_cat` function or `||` operator:

```
postgres=# SELECT array_cat(ARRAY[1,2], ARRAY[3,4]);
 array_cat 
-----------
 {1,2,3,4}
(1 row)

postgres=# SELECT ARRAY[1,2] || ARRAY[3,4];
 ?column?  
-----------
 {1,2,3,4}
(1 row)
```

http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/static/arrays.html

Comment: thanks Pavel, it was the double quote marks. Much appreciated.